# Spring Cloud Eureka Register : Connection refused

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I just want to write a microservice demo basing on `Spring Cloud`, but it goes wrong all the time. Source code as follows:

#### Eureka Server:

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 1111

spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

**Main Class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer; 

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegisterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegisterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Eureka Client:

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-client
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
server:
  port: 1112
```

**Main Class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `Eureka Server` can run successfully. Visiting `http://localhost:1111` shows that:

[image: Eureka Server]

when running `Eureka Client`, it goes wrong, part of error detail as follows:

```
2018-03-13 10:34:30.734 ERROR 1948 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1013) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:927) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:408) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:266) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:262) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
```

I looked up some materials, and the demo refers to a blog post, but I don't know how to modify the code let it run successfully. Thank you for everyone who can help me.

Comment: Try `defaultZone`. `service-url` is a map, `defaultZone` is a key, therefore it is case sensitive.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for your help, I change the `default-zone` to `defaultZone` at your suggestion, it can run without error.

Answer (score 1):

Eureka server also act as a client and it try to register with other Eureka servers. You are getting this error as there is only one Eureka server running and trying to register with other.

If you are planing to have single instance in production or working under development environment, you can disable their registry process( disable client like behaviour)

update your application.properties file with

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```